# What's going on with mdadm --examine here?

Tags: raid, mdadm

I'm trying to figure out why my PCIe attached nvme drives don't seem to be being recognized properly and assembling into the RAID as I expected.

Doing some trouble shooting and looking around this seems to be the best clue from mdadm --examine:

```
mdadm --examine /dev/nvme1n1 
/dev/nvme1n1:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   1953525167 sectors at            1 (type ee)
```

But when I do this with spinning disk raid component I get the usual:

```
mdadm --examine /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 73abfd2e:9332c4dd:6bdf75fc:e457fac6
           Name : functionalgenomics.server:0
  Creation Time : Mon Apr  2 15:06:27 2018
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 19532611584 (9313.88 GiB 10000.70 GB)
     Array Size : 19532611584 (18627.75 GiB 20001.39 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 99d89efb:611f31e0:e18a15d2:4884c89e

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Wed Mar 31 17:25:24 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 13436101 - correct
         Events : 22612

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Any thoughts here? Thanks.